# iBeacon different distance readings on almost every Android device

Tags: android, distance, ibeacon, altbeacon

So I went today to the store to check how different the distance readings of the same beacon really are. I have used "Locate Beacon" app and 3 of my beacons for each of the devices. The results are staggering.

Different devices, even from the same manufacturer gave totally different results. "Samsung Galaxy A5" and "Samsung Galaxy A6" were giving 0.01 for 1m, "Samsung Galaxy S7" 1.5 for 1m. Xiaomi were doing same thing, except "Xiaomi Redmi 5 Plus", which gave exact 1 for 1m.

Frankly speaking I was hoping it will be like one setting for manufacturer, but the amount of differences is just overwhelming.

So how people are dealing with beacons and Android devices when it comes to getting distance? I know that some use cases are relying on the strength of the signal between 2 or more beacons, co the percentage/barycentric coordinate or some other kind of signal triangulation can get the correct position. What with "flagship" example from Apple, when you are int the museum/store and beacon is used to get the proximity from the exposition (I'm assuming the proximity is directly related to distance (accuracy value))?

Is this technology really usable in such context on the Android devices?
Is Eddystone any different in that regard?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of Android, where every device model has a different bluetooth configuration.  For the purposes of RSSI vs. distance, the differences in rough order of importance include:

1. A different bluetooth antenna gain (some are stronger than others)
2. A different bluetooth antenna pattern (some are strong in one direction and weak in another)
3. A different bluetooth chip and different analog to digital converter characteristics for changing the signal level to a digital RSSI reading.
4. A different bluetooth advertisement listening channel hopping rate.  (Some devices change channels once every 10 seconds, others at a sub-second rate.  Each channel will have different signal reception characteristics.)
5. Different firmware at the ROM level that affects the bluetooth stack

The same issues above affect Eddystone distance estimates in the exact same way as iBeacon and AltBeacon.  Physics and hardware are largely what drive this issue.  The beacon format is irrelevant.

For what it's worth, the same issues affect iOS as well.  You absolutely do see different distance estimates on iPads vs. various iPhone models.  However, the variation is much smaller than on Android, which is much more fragmented.

On many Android devices, as you have seen, the variation is similar to different iOS devices.  However there are outliers for sure, and there is no good way to know which device models are the outliers without actually testing with them.

The planned approach with the Android Beacon Library has been do use model-specific distance calculations submitted by the community to adjust the distance estimates for model-specific variations.  While this is technically viable, participation has not been what was hoped. This approach will work if you know the device model you are targeting and can adjust the distance model yourself, there just aren't nearly enough submissions to rely on this approach to have this work reliably across all devices in general.

The bottom line is that if you have a use case that requires converting RSSI to a distance in meters and you need it to work across all Android models you may encounter, you will be disappointed.  Other use cases, however, are more tolerant of such anomalies.

Comment: Hello David. Do you know, if we can use iPhone 5c or iPhone 5s as a reference device for the tests?

Comment: To precise my question: We will probably add some measurements like described here: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/distance-calculations.html but we don't have iPhone 5 at hand. It is easier to get iPhone 5s and cheaper to get iPhone 5c, that is where my question comes from.

Comment: I did the reading following your tutorial, but it is really strange. When I got the values, from your example sheet (found here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ymREowDj40tYuA5CXd4IfC4WYPXxlx5hq1x8tQcWWCI/edit#gid=0) and put them to a regression table: http://www.xuru.org/rt/powr.asp I don't see any value for constant A, which would fit your sheet value. I get result like this: Result:  y = 4.295400587 x^6.170094565
Residual Sum of Squares: rss = 708.1527879
Coefficient of Determination: R2 = 6.733664392·10-1
Your Sheet got values (don't know from where) A=1.203420305, B=6.170094565